# Firebase retention user count mismatch

Tags: firebase, analytics

Hey for mobile app analytics I am using firebase with BigQuery

What I cannot seem to understand is the criteria for the firebase cohort users.

In my firebase dashboard, the monthly retention table shows that for May in Month 0 we have 171 users.

Ok fair enough, but

If I choose the default "unique users" parameter from bigquery events table the unique user count for May is around 500 users.

Ok makes sense so that would mean that the firebase retention dashboard must calculate only new users in each cohort.

However, based on iTunes connect analytics for may we only had 70 downloads. So since we only track the iOS app in firebase I am quite lost as to how the retention cohort groups its respective users.

In short for the month of May:

- I had 70 new downloads
- 500 unique users
- but the firebase retention dashboard shows that we have 171 users in Month 0 for May

So the question is:

By what criteria does the firebase dashboard group their respective users each month?

Thanks